# Ramsey Number proof: $R(3,3,3,3)\leq 4(R(3,3,3)-1) + 2$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I am trying to prove:

> $R(3,3,3,3)\leq 4(R(3,3,3)-1) + 2$

I am confused as to how one can go from a $4$ color problem to a $3$ color problem by multiplying and adding.

edit: $R$ is the Ramsey number

Comment: What is the definition of $r$?

Comment: r is the Ramsey number

Comment: That was sort of clear from the title already. A brief perusal of Wikipedia or MathWorld reveals that the usual definition of the Ramsey number has $R$ taking two arguments, whereas you seem to be using a definition in which $R$ has a variable number of either $3$ or $4$ arguments; hence the request for a definition.

Comment: @joriki: I guess that $R(a,b,c)$ is the size of the smallest complete graph where, if you color the edges with three colors, must contain either a $K_a$ of the first color, a $K_b$ of the second color, or a $K_c$ of the third color. $R(a,b,c,d)$ is similar but with four colors.  This notation is common.

Comment: @joriki And [the Wikipedia article](http://enwp.org/Ramsey_number) explains this in the third paragraph: "An extension of this theorem applies to any finite number of colours, rather than just two. More precisely, the theorem states that for any given number of colours $c$, and any given integers $n_1,\ldots,n_c$, there is a number, $R(n_1, \ldots, n_c)$, such that if the edges of a complete graph of order $R(n_1, \ldots, n_c)$ are coloured with $c$ different colours, then for some $i$ between 1 and $c$, it must contain a complete subgraph of order $n_i$ whose edges are all colour $i$."

Comment: @MJD: I stand corrected :-)

Answer (score 5):

(Big hint/spoiler)

Consider a graph of order $4(R(3,3,3)−1)+2$ whose edges are coloured using four colours. Pick a vertex $x$, and for each $1\leq i\leq 4$ let $V_i$ denote the set of vertices whose edge to $x$ uses the $i$'th colour. By the pigeonhole principle, some $V_i$ has order at least $R(3,3,3)$. Now consider two cases:

- some edge in $V_i$ uses colour $i$
- no edge in $V_i$ uses colour $i$