# Proving an inequality on Ramsey numbers by induction: $t_{r+1} \leq (r+1) (t_r - 1) + 2$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, recurrence-relations, induction, ramsey-theory

Not sure how to proceed. I'm trying to prove that the following inequality is true. I know that $t_2 = 6$ and $t_3=17$ from the problem statement. The base case is obvious.

$t_{r+1} \leq (r+1) (t_r - 1) + 2$

($t_r$ is supposed to be the [Ramsey number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers) $R(3,3,3,\ldots,3)$ with $r$ $3$s).

Comment: sorry, does that clarify?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307970/ramsey-number-proof) gives a big hint for case $r=3$; this hint generalizes easily to arbitrary $r$.