# How do I get this upper bound for Ramsey numbers: $R_k \le \left \lfloor k!e \right \rfloor + 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

For every integer $k \ge 2$,

$$R_k \le \left \lfloor k!e \right \rfloor + 1$$

where $R_k$ denotes $R(\underbrace{{3, 3, \ldots, 3}}_{k})$.

Comment: I am not sure whether this helps here, but [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314097/proving-an-inequality-on-ramsey-numbers-by-induction-t-r1-leq-r1-t-r) is another question about $R_k$. No answer was posted so far, but comments there suggest that it can proved similarly to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307970/ramsey-number-proof-r3-3-3-3-leq-4r3-3-3-1-2).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Using $R_{k+1}\le(k+1)(R_k-1)+2$ I can even get a stronger bound $R_k\le2n!+2$?

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that there should be equality? Maybe it would be worth mentioning the source of the problem. (It is advised to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).) And if you thing you have proof of the result, you can post it as an answer. add it to your question or as a separate question. That way there is a chance that some other users will have a look at your proof and point out mistakes if there are some.

Comment: In [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0118%28199711%2926:3%3C119::AID-JGT1%3E3.0.CO;2-U/abstract) the author derives the inequality $R_n \le n! \left(\frac{e+e^{-1}+3}2\right) +1$. I found a reference to this result [here](http://www.cs.oswego.edu/~fettes/thesis.ps).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you! I was wrong about the bound $R_k \le 2n! + 2$, sorry. I have asked a new question pointing out the source of this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718704/how-do-i-find-the-ramsey-number-r-6).

Comment: See also the recently posted question: [At least one monochromatic triangle from $p_n=\lfloor{en!}\rfloor+1$ points](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2125977)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following text is quoted from the paper
R. E. Greenwood, A. M. Gleason: *Combinatorial relations and chromatic graphs*, Canad. J. Math. 7(1955), 1-7, [DOI: 10.4153/CJM-1955-001-4](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1955-001-4).

> **5. Upper and Lower Bounds for $n(3^r)$.** Let $t_r=n(3^r)=n(3,3,\dots,3)$. The upper bounds used in Theorems 1, 4 and 5 can all be obtained by the
>   use of
>
> THEOREM 6.
>   $$t_{r+1} \le (r+1)(t_r-1)+2.$$
>
> This theorem is easily proved by induction; and then it is trivial to establish, also by induction, that
>   $$t_{r+1} \le 3(r+1)!.$$
>   A somewhat sharper inequality may be obtained, however, without any added difficulties. It has already been established that
>   $$t_r \le \lfloor (r!)e \rfloor +1, \qquad r=2,3,4,$$
>   where $\lfloor M \rfloor$ means the greatest integer contained in $M$. 
>   Such a bound holds for all integers $r\ge 2$, for if it did not there would be a least integer, say $s+1$, for which the relation failed to hold.
>   By Theorem 6,
>   $$t_{s+1} \le (s+1) \lfloor (s!)e \rfloor+2, \qquad s\ge2$$
>   But $\lfloor (s+1)!e \rfloor = (s+1) \lfloor (s!)e \rfloor +1$, and hence
>   $$t_{s+1} \le  \lfloor (s+1)!e \rfloor +1$$
>   and the stated upper bound follows.

A proof of the inequality stated as Theorem 6 can also be found here: [Ramsey Number Inequality: $R(\underbrace{3,3,...,3,3}_{k+1}) \le (k+1)(R(\underbrace{3,3,...3}_k)-1)+2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314013/ramsey-number-inequality-r-underbrace3-3-3-3-k1-le-k1r-underb)